# Center ul (images) horizontally

Tags: css

Having problems centering a ul horizontally within a div. The list doesn't contain any text, just images.

I'm using the list to display social media icons in the footer of my website.

Thought it would be easy enough to do but I've I've exhausted all methods I can think of, can anyone help? I'm probably missing the obvious :/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div id="footer">
    <div id="social_media">
        <ul>
            <li class="youtube"><a href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="flickr"><a href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="googleplus"><a href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 700px;
}
#footer {
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:100px;
}
#social_media {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  float:left;
}
#social_media ul {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
#social_media li {
  list-style: none;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#social_media li a, #social_media li {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#social_media ul li.youtube {
  background-position: -88px 0;
}
#social_media ul li.flickr {
  background-position: -132px 0;
}
#social_media ul li.googleplus {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
#social_media ul li.linkedin {
  background-position: -44px 0;
}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/SZ27u](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ27u/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set `text-align:center` on the parent, `.container`, and then remove `width:100%` and `float:left` on `#social_media`, and change `display: block` to `display:inline-block`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/D92zC/)

```
.container {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
}

#social_media {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a technique called shrink wrapping.  This will also work with multiple floated children.  The relevant styles are:

```
#footer > div {
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   left: -50%;
}
#social_media {
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SZ27u/2/

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/SZ27u/1/)

So you have to define a width for the `margin: auto;` to work. This is a good way to do what you want.

```
#social_media ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 256px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option assumes you know what the width iof the UL should be based on the width of your LI's.  It also assumes that setting a specific width for the element is ok based on your template.

Simply change these bits of CSS to the following:

(deleted the float and added width and overflow)

```
#social_media ul {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 256px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SZ27u/3/